# Relationships and conditional problems

Tags: relationships, conditionals

I have a **Facilities** channel and a **Jobs** channel. The Facilities entries have multiple fields with facility info. The Jobs channel has a title field and a relationship field that allows a user to select which facility the job belongs with. In my template I want to list the job entries, divided by state (states are assigned to entries using categories, but I'm trying to simplify by having a channel entry that only displays one category for each state ). There are 5 states total with facilities so there are actually 5 channel entry tags in the template, I have posted 2 below.

```
            {exp:channel:entries channel="facilities" disable="member_data|category_fields" category="1" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}

            {parents}
            {if count == "1"}
            <h2>Iowa</h2>
            <div class="state_wrap">
            {/if}
                  {if parents:count == "1"}
                    <article class="job_summary">
                        <h1><a href="/{url_title}">{title}</a> - <span class="city">{facility_contact_info limit="1"}{facility_contact_info:address}{city}{/facility_contact_info:address}{/facility_contact_info}</span></h1>
                        <h2><span class="accent">Openings:</span> &nbsp;
                  {/if}

                       {parents:title}{if parents:count >= "1" AND parents:count != parents:total_results},&nbsp;{/if}

                  {if parents:count == parents:total_results}
                        </h2>
                       {facility_contact_info}<p><a href="{facility_contact_info:joblink}">Apple Online &raquo;</a></p>{/facility_contact_info}
                    </article>
                  {/if}

            {if count == total_results}</div>{/if}
            {/parents}

            {/exp:channel:entries}



            {exp:channel:entries channel="facilities" disable="member_data|category_fields" category="2" sort="asc" dynamic="no"}

            {parents}
            {if count == "1"}
            <h2>Missouri</h2>
            <div class="state_wrap">
            {/if}
                  {if parents:count == "1"}
                    <article class="job_summary">
                        <h1><a href="/{url_title}">{title}</a> - <span class="city">{facility_contact_info limit="1"}{facility_contact_info:address}{city}{/facility_contact_info:address}{/facility_contact_info}</span></h1>
                        <h2><span class="accent">Openings:</span> &nbsp;
                  {/if}

                       {parents:title}{if parents:count >= "1" AND parents:count != parents:total_results},&nbsp;{/if}

                  {if parents:count == parents:total_results}
                        </h2>
                       {facility_contact_info}<p><a href="{facility_contact_info:joblink}">Apple Online &raquo;</a></p>{/facility_contact_info}
                    </article>
                  {/if}

            {if count == total_results}</div>{/if}
            {/parents}

            {/exp:channel:entries}
```

The part that is proving difficult is getting  the conditionals setup correctly so that for each state, only if there are job postings(relationship field), it will put the name of the state in the H2 tag, then open a DIV with class "state_wrap". So then the parents tag runs and displays all the jobs for each facility in that state. Once that state is done, it's supposed to close the "state_wrap" DIV. I've tried many different ways of getting this to output correctly, but it's just not working. Is there any way for me to modify my current template code to work? Or another way to display the entries that will work? Thanks for any help!

I really just need to detect if there are any parents outside of the {parents} tag, I think I can work my conditionals to function correctly then. I tried something like...

```
{if "{parents:job_facility:total_results}" > 0}
{parents}
...
{/parents}
{/if}
```

I get a PHP error with quotes and brackets around parents:job_facility:total_results and get no results without them. Should this conditional work? I'm using EE v2.9.0, maybe this is a bug?

Comment: Do you need a relationship field in your parents tags, e.g. `{parents field="relationship_field"}`?

Comment: I added that and it didn't make a difference.

Comment: I've read this question 3 times! because parse order and EE conditionals are often quite difficult would you be willing to edit and add 2 example of your desired output? One with no parents, one with a few? Otherwise I would suggest you seperate your <h2> coee into a subtemplate and use the embed tag, feeding in parent:count. It may be that the conditional is parsed before the parent tags, ego at the time the if is parsed there is no number to compare against... If you can give me an idea of data structure and desired output I might be able to find some time later to run up a test/solution...